# Unable to build apk: The number of method references cannot exceed 64K

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I have been trying to build the apk file for my app, however, I am getting the error: The number of method references cannot exceed 64K.

Here are the errors,

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is my gradle file,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nikhilraghavendra.hopper"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

I want to build the apk file and deploy it without any issues, how do I do it?

**Update**

I also tried the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount = 4 // this is the default value
}

dataBinding{
    enabled = true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nikhilraghavendra.hopper"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    resConfigs "en", "fr"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

This is producing the message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'.

> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

How do I deal with this and build a proper apk? Please Help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

you have to enable Multidex, Please follow above link

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.try.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

here `multiDexEnabled true` should do the game for you

**UPDATE : To support latest Android version**
1. If your `minSdkVersion` is set to **21** or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown above.
2. However, if your `minSdkVersion` is set to **20** or lower, then you must use the multidex support library along with above changes as follows:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Apart from the above addition of support library, you need to make changes to your Application class as mentioned in this [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

**BEST PRACTICE:**
1. Remove any unused code with proguard.
2. Avoid adding unnecessary dependencies in your project.
3. If limited number methods or classes of any open source library are needed, then its advisable to clone only those in your project as it not only gives you total control on them but also allows proguard to act on them and you don't have any unused methods in your code.

Source : [Android Developers - Configure Apps with 64K Method count](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Just that? What about the rest described here? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Hi @AndrewS, thanks for pointing this stuff out. This answer is not updated since a while, will update it soon. Thanks

Comment: When will you update your answer? All of us are waiting for your update

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki this answer works for basic project. Please make a try

Answer (score 31):

Unable to build apk: The number of method references cannot exceed 64K occur when app .dex file have more than 65,536 methods.

**Exceed 65K Method** that means method count more than 65,536 methods
There are different ways to fix it:

**1. Reduce dependencies in your project
put dependencies in gradle which are required**

Most problems that I found from another developers is use Google Play Services in them project like this.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play‐services:8.4.0'
```

So the best way is choosing only some dependencies in Google Play Services that you really want to
use it.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play‐services‐location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play‐services‐maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play‐services‐ads:8.4.0'
```

**2. Set minimum SDK version to 21 or higher**

Why it worked when change minimum SDK to 21? That's because of Android 5.0 or higher are use ART
(Android Runtime) that supported MultiDex instead of Dalvik. So ART can support more than 65,536
methods.

**3. Use Proguard to reduce useless method**

**4. Use MultiDex**

But these are the Limitation of MultiDex library

• May occurs ANR while app launching if .dex files too large.

• Should be define minimum SDK to version 14 or higher.

• MulitDex uses more memory and may crash while app running if allocation memory is over limit.

• Take more build time when you build the project

Comment: Dont play with your google-service dependencies guys acording to this explanation. if you have a working system my gradle is down right now.. (

Comment: Upvoted. What for all this maths with multidex?  Also there is an operation  with shrinkings as well.   https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup   Here is a list of splitted services. Just pick up what to use .

Answer (score 6):

Put this inside your `defaultConfig`:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```